# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter overrides EnableResourceServer?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have perfectly working spring boot app which use spring oAuth2. when i use @EnableResourceServer on main class it worked well. 
but to enable CORS for services I have implemented below class

```
   @Configuration
    public class CorsConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf().disable();
            http.cors();

        }
        @Bean
        public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            final org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration configuration = new org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
                    "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
            configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
   configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
            final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
        }
    }
```

After I add that class it seems request does not validate with oAuth token. any request even without oAuth token can access service.

What I did wrong? 
Cant I use both? is there any special thing to do both to work?
is there any better way to enable CORS that this. (I tried @CrossOrigin annotation it didn't worked)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure why you wanted to use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
I think your problem is you are not forwarding your calls to oAuth for authorize. try this it worked for me

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration configuration = new org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(ImmutableList.of("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(ImmutableList.of("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("resource");
    }

}
```

here this  `resources.resourceId("resource");` should be resource you have used in your oAuth server

similar method like this

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("clinet").secret("secret").accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600).scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").resourceIds("resource");
    }
```